# posting Flask wtforms in loop and saving data

Tags: python, flask, e-commerce, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have a *Flask-WTF* form fields in for loop. I want to post the new quantities for each item.

I am reading about field list. I still dont understand but i think they might be the answer.

```
@app.route('/checkout')
def checkout():
   form = CartForm()
    for item in current_user.cart:
        product = Product.query.get(item.product_id)
        cart_items.append({product: item.quantity})

    return render_template('checkout.html',cart_items=cart_items,form=form)



{% for item in cart_items %}
    {% for product, quantity in item.items() %}
        {{product.name}}
        {{product.price}}
        {{form.quantity }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Problem1: When looping over each  Each *Flask-WTF* form field has the same name.

The output

```
<select id="quantity" name="quantity"><option value="1">1</option></select>
<select id="quantity" name="quantity"><option value="1">1</option></select>
```

problem2: how save in the backed if each form has a different name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem exactly! But I solve it without Flask-WTF, the solution below was based on my app. I have an album edit page, I need to loop a text input for each picture in album, then save the text for each picture.

I loop the input in HTML, notice I set the action value for another view function and **use each photo's id as each text input's name**:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('edit_photo', id=album.id) }}" method="POST">
<ul>
    {% for photo in photos %}
    <li>
        <img class="img-responsive portrait" src="{{ photo.path }}" alt="Some description"/>
        <textarea name="{{ photo.id }}" placeholder="add some description" rows="3">{% if photo.description %}{{ photo.description }}{% endif %}</textarea>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
<hr>
<input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
```

Then I loop the picture and save the input data (**get it's value by it's id**):

```
@app.route('/edit-photo/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def edit_photo(id):
    album = Album.query.get_or_404(id)
    photos = album.photos.order_by(Photo.order.asc())
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for photo in photos:
            photo.about = request.form[str(photo.id)]
            db.session.add(photo)
        return redirect(url_for('.album', id=id))
    return render_template('edit_photo.html', album=album, photos=photos)
```

Comment: its not what i wanted because i wanted to give them unique names so i can add things with javascript for this was helpful thankyou very much

Comment: Notice I use `photo.id` for name value:  `name="{{ photo.id }}"`, so every input will have a unique name.